# Python Backend Next JS Front end malloc err

Tags: python, backend

I am calling my python flask backend through my next js front end like this:

```
await fetch('http://localhost:8080/get-facial-data', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ frame: imageData })
})
```

Here is my python backend server.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

from flask_cors import CORS
import base64
import dlib
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import random
import numpy as np
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

@app.route('/get-facial-data', methods=['POST'])
def get_facial_data():
    frame_data = request.json['frame']
    frame_bytes = base64.b64decode(frame_data.split(',')[1])
    frame_array = np.frombuffer(frame_bytes, dtype=np.uint8)
    frame = cv2.imdecode(frame_array, flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    
    # Convert the frame to grayscale for facial landmark detection
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    if gray is None:
        return {'error': 'Invalid image format'}
            
    # Detect faces in the frame
    faces = detector(gray)
    
    # Check the number of faces detected
    if len(faces) == 0:
        return {'error': 'No faces detected'}
    elif len(faces) > 1:
        return {'error': 'Multiple faces detected'}
    
    # Iterate over detected faces
    for face in faces:
        # Detect facial landmarks
        landmarks = predictor(gray, face)
    
        # Draw facial landmarks on the frame
        for n in range(0, 68):
            x = landmarks.part(n).x
            y = landmarks.part(n).y
            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)
    
    _, modified_frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    modified_frame_data = base64.b64encode(modified_frame).decode('utf-8')
    
    return {'modifiedFrame': f'data:image/jpeg;base64,{modified_frame_data}', 'error': None}

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

And I am getting the following error randomly, usually when the front end starts making the first few requests:

```
Python(75467,0x302c9b000) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fb41401ba10: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x3cc7d1653c15c498
Python(75467,0x302c9b000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

and this causes my backend file to stop running. Sometimes, that error is not even shown and my backend just stops running suddenly with no error.
I am running my backend script with python3 server.py

Here is the console when I run the website when the error occurs

```
POST http://localhost:8080/get-facial-data net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I don't really know what to try because this error does not have much information on it. I have reset my environment and VSCode but it didn't do anything.